# LINQ to Entities -- OrderBy().ToList() vs. ToList().OrderBy()

Tags: performance, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm looking for confirmation/clarification with these LINQ expressions:

```
var context = new SomeCustomDbContext()

// LINQ to Entities?
var items  = context.CustomItems.OrderBy(i => i.Property).ToList();

// LINQ to Objects?
var items2 = context.CustomItems.ToList().OrderBy(i => i.Property);
```

1. Am I correct in thinking the first method is `LINQ to Entities` where EF builds a more specific SQL statement to pass on, putting the ordering effort on on the database?
2. Is the second method `LINQ to Objects` where LINQ drags the whole collection into memory (the `ToList()` enumeration?) before ordering thus leaving the burden on the server side (the web server in this case)?

   If this is the case, I can quickly see situations where L2E would be advantageous (ex. filtering/trimming collections before pulling them into memory).
3. But are there any other details/trade-offs I should be aware of, or times when "method 2" might be advantageous over the first method?

**UPDATE:**

Let's say we are not using EntityFramework, this is still true so long as the underlying repository/data source implements `IQueryable<T>` right? And if it doesn't both these statements result in `LINQ to Objects` operations in memory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Yes.
3. Yes.

You are correct that calling `ToList()` forces linq-to-entities to evaluate and return the results as a list. As you suspect, this can have huge performance implications.

There are cases where linq-to-entities cannot figure out how to parse what looks like a perfectly simple query (like `Where(x => SomeFunction(x))`). In these cases you often have no choice but to call `ToList()` and operate on the collection in memory.

---

In response to your update:

`ToList()` always forces everything ahead of it to evaluate immediately, as opposed to deferred execution. Take this example:

```
someEnumerable.Take(10).ToList();
```

vs

```
someEnumerable.ToList().Take(10);
```

In the second example, any deferred work on `someEnumerable` must be executed before taking the first 10 elements. If `someEnumerable` is doing something labor intensive (like reading files from the disk using `Directory.EnumerateFiles()`), this could have very real performance implications.

Comment: Thank you. Can you see my Update and more importantly the comment to D Stanly's answer above?

Comment: @JonB: Can you shed more light on this: "There are cases where linq-to-entities cannot figure out how to parse what looks like a perfectly simple query (like Where(x => SomeFunction(x)))."?

Comment: @Pawel Equals() is a method that comes to mind, which LINQ to ENTITIES converts it to a LINQ to SQL statement.

Comment: @Pawel, JonB. Thanks. Exactly what was needed. Though I too would love an example of `Equals()` or similar translation issue.

Comment: @JonB - I am having a hard time to grok your comment. Did you mean Sql and not Linq to Sql? Can you be more specific about Equals - I tried the following and - as long as I have the correct type - it works: `var s = ctx.tasks.Where(t => t.task_id.Equals(Guid.NewGuid())).ToList();`

Comment: @Pawel When using linq-to-entities, EF has to parse your LINQ into something else (like SQL). It can't do that if there's no equivalent for something in your query (like a function call). Using EF and SQL, doing a `myTable.Where(x => x.Equals(...))` will cause a runtime error. I'm not an EF guru, so I might not be able to explain much more. The key here is that calling `ToList()` will bring everything back into the linq-to-objects domain, which is is simpler and more powerful -- but potentially MUCH slower.

Comment: Yes. Linq to Entity query is translated to database specific SQL. Yes - EF will throw if there is no translation to SQL. Equals (as shown above) should work unless you are comparing to an object EF does not understand and therefore is not able to translate to SQL. However if you use such an object it probably means that your business logic is leaking to the database and database will never be able to compare column values with random data so you need to separate these. Yes - .ToList() forces query evaluation and can bring the whole database to the client therefore you need to write...

Comment: ... a query that makes sense and returns only what you need to do further filtering on the client. If you find that you need to double filter your data constantly (once in the database and then once more on the client) maybe it's time to extend your database to understand one more entity and be able to do everything on the database side? Also note that you cannot expect Equals to work for references since EF materializes objects from database data and the reference is different each time so the result will always be false.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I correct in thinking the first method is LINQ to Entities where EF builds a more specific SQL statement to pass on, putting the ordering effort on on the database?

Yes

> Is the second method LINQ to Objects where LINQ drags the whole collection into memory ... before ordering thus leaving the burden on the server side ...?

Yes

> But are there any other details/trade-offs I should be aware of, or times when "method 2" might be advantageous over the first method?

There will be many times where Method 1 is not possible - usually when you have a complex filter or sort order that can't be directly translated to SQL (or more appropriately where EF does not support a direct SQL translation).  Also since you can't transmit lazy-loaded `IQueryable`s over-the-wire, any time you have to serialize a result you're going to have to materialize it first with `ToList()` or something similar.

Comment: I think you just answered my update too -- in the case that the source only implements IEnumerable<T> these statements are essentially no different?

Comment: Not necessarily; `IEnumerable<T>` can be implemented in a lazy manner as well.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing to be aware of is that IQueryable makes no guarantees on either (a) the semantic reasoning of the underlying provider, or (b) how much of the set of IQueryable methods are implemented by the provider.

For example: -

1. EF does not support Last().
2. Nor does it support time-part comparisons of DateTimes into valid T-SQL.
3. It doesn't support FirstOrDefault() in subqueries.

In such circumstances you need to bring data back to the client and then perform further evaluation client-side.

You also need to have an understanding of "how" it parses the LINQ pipeline to generate (in the case of EF) T-SQL. So you sometimes have to think carefully about how you construct your LINQ queries in order to generate effective T-SQL.

Having said all that, IQueryable<> is an extremely powerful tool in the .NET framework and well worth getting more familiar with.