# Entity Framework object LINQ query Timeout issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, timeout, executiontimeout

I've attempted to modify my connection string to include an extended timeout and I've confirmed that on the sql server side the view that feeds my EF Object executes within seconds and returns a total of 3000 or less records.

BUT when I attempt to run it via code I am now running into Timeout issues and I was seeking some advice to fix this issue. I get "Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."
Most solutions I find on the specific error recommend connection string modifications OR something along this.context.CommandTimeout... which I cannot figure out how to use in this situation.

I've included the Method I use to acquire the desired data. If there is a more efficient way please let me know.

The input arguments are:

- `int? inputSKU = null`
- `int? inputStoreNum = null`
- `DateTime? inputStartDate = null`

The intent is to return the full list.

And it hangs at, because it skips all the conditional bits:
`var qUniqueOffers = query.GroupBy(q => q.Plan_Number).ToList();`

Thank you.

---

```
private List<PromotionItem> QueryPromotion(int? inputSKU, int? inputStoreNum, DateTime? inputStartDate)
{
    log.Info("Client requested QueryPromotion");
    List<PromotionItem> resultQuery = new List<PromotionItem>();

    try
    {
        using (DWH_Entities db = new DWH_Entities())
        {
            var query = db.vw_Web_Promotion.AsQueryable();

            // filter promotion results that don't match SKU#
            if (inputSKU != null)
                query = query.Where(q => q.Sku_Number == inputSKU);
            // filter promotion results that don't match Store Num
            if (inputStoreNum != null)
                query = query.Where(q => q.Store_Number == inputStoreNum);
            // filter promotion results that don't match Promotion Start Date
            if (inputStartDate != null)
                query = query.Where(q => q.Start_Date >= inputStartDate);
            // Group promotions By Plan Number ('Promotion ID')
            var qUniqueOffers = query
                                .GroupBy(q => q.Plan_Number)
                                .ToList();
            // Select first from each group to get unique details
            var qOffers = qUniqueOffers
                        .Select(g => g.OrderBy(gi => gi.Plan_Number).First())
                        .ToList();

            foreach (var qo in qOffers)
            {
                resultQuery.Add(new PromotionItem
                {
                    PromotionNumber = qo.Plan_Number.Trim(),
                    PromotionDescription = qo.Plan_Description.Trim(),
                    StartDate = qo.Start_Date,
                    EndDate = qo.End_Date
                });
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.Error("[" + e.TargetSite + "] | " + e.Message);
        throw e;
    }

    return resultQuery;
}
```

Comment: What line is generating the `Execution Timeout Expired` exception? Can you show us a screenshot of it?

Comment: @mjwills in reference to this code block. Line 22. It hits the breakpoint I set there and when I continue on it cranks for 30 seconds or so then throws the timeout exception. var qUniqueOffers = query.GroupBy(q => q.Plan_Number).ToList();

Comment: TejasVaishnav posted a solution that extended my timeout, but sadly I believe my query/application is not as optimized as it could be as it still times out after 300 seconds. I will attempt to rewrite.

Comment: What happens if you remove ToList from `var qUniqueOffers = query
                                .GroupBy(q => q.Plan_Number)
                                .ToList()` ? Does that improve things?

Comment: @mjwills you know what. I think that did the trick. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Group promotions By Plan Number ('Promotion ID')
var qUniqueOffers = query
                    .GroupBy(q => q.Plan_Number)
                    .ToList();
// Select first from each group to get unique details
var qOffers = qUniqueOffers
            .Select(g => g.OrderBy(gi => gi.Plan_Number).First())
            .ToList();
```

The way you have written the above LINQ means you are pulling a lot of data over the wire (the first `ToList`) and then getting a subset of the data (using `First` and the second `ToList`). Consider changing it to:

```
// Group promotions By Plan Number ('Promotion ID')
var qUniqueOffers = query
                    .GroupBy(q => q.Plan_Number)
// Select first from each group to get unique details
var qOffers = qUniqueOffers
            .Select(g => g.OrderBy(gi => gi.Plan_Number).First())
            .ToList();
```

This should result in **much** less data being sent from the database - which will hopefully make it faster.

As https://stackoverflow.com/a/13827077/34092 states:

> ToList() always forces everything ahead of it to evaluate immediately,
>   as opposed to deferred execution.

Comment: mjwills thank you for the detailed answer. I will add that as a result I had to modify the .First() to .FirstorDefault() because it was throwing an syntax exception.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using latest EF version do the following to increase timeout:

```
using (DWH_Entities db = new DWH_Entities())
{
    db.Database.CommandTimeout = 300;
    ...
```

If you want records in the minimum time, try following:

```
var temp = query.ToList();
var qUniqueOffers = temp.GroupBy(q => q.Plan_Number)
                                .ToList();
```

Comment: TejasVaishnav Thank you. Using EF6, and this helps address my initial question about extending the timeout. I did have to modify "context" to "db" because of the value I assigned to my object, but it extended the run time db.Database.CommandTimeout = 300;

Comment: My bad, edited for others, thanks for letting it know

Comment: I don't know why you aren't getting some love for this answer.  db.Database.CommandTimeout worked.  So many people over complicate answers, yours is perfect. Keep up the good work. Good day sir.